# When does mc api rest for journey respond with "The contact status should be Active"

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, rest

We are getting the error

```
HTTP/1.1 400
{
    "message": "The contact status should be Active.",
    "errorcode": 30000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

when adding a contact into a journey with the REST call:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postEvent.html

I've tried with no luck to reproduce the error by using a subscriber with 'Unsubscribed' status with no luck, the response is 201 created.

Does anyone knows when and why the "The contact status should be Active" error appears?

Comment: when the contact is being deleted/suppressed

Comment: @EazyE can you add this comment as a response? So I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

This means the customer is in one of the following states:

1. The customer has been deleted - Per deletion process in Contact Builder, see more details [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/contact-deletion-in-marketing-cloud/delete-contacts-in-contact-builder)
2. OR, the customer is suppressed due to the exit criteria of the Journey you are attempted to post an event to.

   - For example: Journey has an exit criteria to Exit on day 1, see image below.
   - You trigger the postEvent on 2023-02-06 12:00:00 AM
   - If you trigger the postEvent again, you will get this error from the API
   - Once the Exit criteria has been met, and the contact has exited the Journey, you will be able to trigger the postEvent again without error
     [image]